# Why can I connect to a Synapse serverless SQL pool but cannot connect to a dedicated SQL pool in the same Synapse Workspace

Tags: azure, networking, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-link

Recently, we deployed a dedicated SQL Pool to a Synapse Workspace in production. In development we can access both the serverless SQL pool and the dedicated SQL pool. However, in production we can access the serverless SQL pool, but we cannot reach the dedicated SQL pool (either in the portal where upon trying to view the database objects we get an AjaxError or when trying to connect via SSMS where we get a Named Pipes Error message):

[Named Pipes Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y3HC.png)

Both the development and the production Synapse instance have private endpoints (in separate vnets and subnets). We access both using a VM that is associated to a virtual network that is peered with the network with the private endpoints of the Synapse instances.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

AJAX Error when selecting the database and running a statement against it in the Develop Widget

[image]

**Cause and Mitigation**

- Local network is restricting access to the SQL Logical Services on Port 443 and Port 1443.
- Allow access to the services on the specified ports which would grant
  access to the web endpoint of the database services.

**Source:** [Synapse Workspace Pools and On Demand Inaccessible](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/synapse-workspace-pools-and-on-demand-inaccessible/ba-p/1403485)

**Additional Useful link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-portal

Answer (score -1):

I just disconnected from VPN and it worked!